# Concrete method with wide template method

Tags: swift

I have factory with 2 methods, one generic tamplate and one with wrapped result:

```
class Service {
    func action() {
        print("action in service")
    }
    required init() {
    }
}

class Resolver {
    typealias Factory = () -> Any

    private var registrations = [String: Factory]()

    func register(factory: @escaping Factory, forType type: Any.Type) {
        registrations[self.key(for: type)] = factory
    }

    func resolve<T>() -> T {
        let key = key(for: T.self)
        let factory = registrations[key]
        let result = factory?() as! T
        return result
    }

    private func key(for type: Any.Type) -> String {
        return ObjectIdentifier(type).debugDescription
    }
}

class Weak<T: AnyObject> {

    private(set) weak var obj: T?

    init(_ obj: T) {
        self.obj = obj
    }
}

extension Resolver {
    func resolve<T>() -> Weak<T> {
        Weak<T>(self.resolve())
    }
}

let resolver = Resolver()
resolver.register(factory: {
    return Service()
}, forType: Service.self)


let s: Service = resolver.resolve()
let weakS: Weak<Service> = resolver.resolve() // here I have error
```

How I can create method with same name to return wrapped value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a metatype parameter to the `resolve` methods so Swift has more information to determine which overload you are calling:

```
func resolve<T>(_ type: T.Type) -> T {
    let key = key(for: T.self)
    let factory = registrations[key]
    let result = factory?() as! T
    return result
}

// ...

func resolve<T>(_ type: T.Type) -> Weak<T> {
    Weak<T>(self.resolve(type))
}
```

```
let s = resolver.resolve(Service.self) // not weak
let weakS: Weak<Service> = resolver.resolve(Service.self) // weak
```

You don't actually need to have this parameter on both `resolve`s, but you seem to want to have the same call site for both.

If I were you, I would add the metatype parameter to only the `Weak` method. This looks more "symmetrical" to me:

```
let s: Service = resolver.resolve()
let weakS: Weak<_> = resolver.resolve(Service.self)
```

as opposed to:

```
let s = resolver.resolve(Service.self)
let weakS: Weak<Service> = resolver.resolve()
```

Comment: Thank you for Idea. Just add default values into signatures and all works :): 
func resolve<T>(_ type: T.Type = T.self) -> T
func resolve<T>(_ type: T.Type = T.self) -> Weak<T>

let s: Service = resolver.resolve()
let weakS: Weak<Service> = resolver.resolve()